# Oracle Apex 23.2 hidden layers on map causing javascript zooming loop

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I'm learning Oracle Apex using a free workspace, so I'm on the 23,2 version.

I am trying to recreate the "Search and Show" feature you can find on the Airport Sample app (page 121) and it works fine for the most part.

You click on a link in the list of items, which triggers a javascript that zooms the map in on the linked object. But the problem in my case, is that after it takes me to the object, if I try to zoom the map in or out, it loads/refreshes the map, triggering the javascript and it zooms me back on the previously clicked on object and keeps on doing that ad infinitum.

I've discovered this is happens if I have any hidden layers.

So, unlike the sample app, I have several map layers, that display objects based on WHERE statements, that aren't always met, so sometimes 2 of 8 layers are not displaying at all. They're not even in the legends checkboxes because they have nothing to display currently.
I also have 2 layers that have objects to display but the information on them isn't the most important so they are turned off by default.

The moment i get these layers to actually be visible or if I comment them out, the function works as intended, it zooms the map in on the object once and that's it, you can freely zoom the map around.

Is there a way to fix this without using dummy objects to display the hidden layers?

For the record, i could also re-create this issue on the sample app by just duplicating the layer and making it not show up by adding a WHERE to the SQL query for it.

This is the javascript I am using, it is pretty much the same as on the sample app apart from ID's, layer names and such.

```
var lMapRegion = apex.region("Map_Maintenance"),
    layerNames = [
        "TEST1",
        "TEST1_SCHEDULED",
        "TEST1_DONE",
        "TEST2",
        "TEST2_SCHEDULED",
        "TEST2_DONE",
        "TEST3",
        "TEST3_DONE"
    ],
    lCurrentZoom = lMapRegion.call("getMapCenterAndZoomLevel").zoom,
    lOBJEKTUM_ID = apex.item("P2_ID").getValue(),
    lPosition;

for (var i = 0; i < layerNames.length; i++) {
    var lLayerId = lMapRegion.call("getLayerIdByName", layerNames[i]),
        lFeature = lMapRegion.call("getFeature", lLayerId, lOBJEKTUM_ID);

    if (lFeature.geometry) {
        lPosition = lFeature.geometry.coordinates;

        lMapRegion.call("closeAllInfoWindows");
        lMapRegion.call("setCenter", lPosition);

        if (lCurrentZoom < 12) {
            lMapRegion.call("setZoomLevel", 12);
        }

        setTimeout(function () {
            lMapRegion.call("displayPopup", "infoWindow", lLayerId, lOBJEKTUM_ID.toString(), false);
        }, 500);
    }
}
```